# How to pause the program (game) like the usual games when esc key is clicked?

Tags: c++

I'm using turbo c++ 4.0 compiler. We have given a project to make a game. I want to create a text-based adventure. Well in the middle of my coding, I just thought that if a user wants to exit, it must have a key to pause the game or exit the game like the esc key.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<stdio.h>
char namee[100];
char mf[100];
char mfc[100];
char ch;

void item()
{
 int hold=2,sawnd=20;
  for(int snd=50;snd>0;snd--)
  { sawnd=(sawnd*hold);
   sound(sawnd);
   delay(50);
  }
  nosound();
 }

void letter()
{
 int hold=10,hld=49;
 for(int y=15;y<21;y++)
  {
   textcolor(15),gotoxy(y,hold),cprintf("ß");
   gotoxy(hld,hold),cprintf("ß");
   hold=hold+1;
   hld=hld-1;
  }
 }

void letter1()
{
 for(int p=20;p<61;p++)
 {
  textcolor(15),gotoxy(p,2),cprintf("ß");
  delay(5);
  gotoxy(p,23),cprintf("ß");
 }
 for(int o=2;o<24;o++)
 {
  textcolor(15),gotoxy(20,o),cprintf("ß");
  delay(5);
  gotoxy(60,o),cprintf("ß");
 }
 textcolor(15),gotoxy(23,5),cprintf("To my beloved friend,");
 delay(100);
}

void box2()
{
 for(int i=14;i<=50;i++)
  {
   textcolor(15),gotoxy(i,9);cprintf("ß");
   delay(5);
   gotoxy(i,17);cprintf("ß");
  }
 for(int j=9;j<=17;j++)
  {
   textcolor(15),gotoxy(14,j);cprintf("ß");
   delay(5);
   gotoxy(50,j);cprintf("ß");
  }
 for(int u=21;u<45;u++)
 {
  textcolor(15),gotoxy(u,15),cprintf("ß");
  delay(5);
 }
}

void box(int x, int y, int x2, int y2)
{
 clrscr();
 for(int i=x;i<=y;i++)
  {
   gotoxy(i,x2);cout<<char(15);
   delay(5);
   gotoxy(i,y2);cout<<char(15);
  }
 for(int j=x;j<=y2;j++)
  {
   gotoxy(x,j);cout<<char(15);
   delay(5);
   gotoxy(y,j);cout<<char(15);
  }
}
void box1(int x, int y, int x2, int y2)
{
 clrscr();
 for(int i=x;i<=y;i++)
  {
   gotoxy(i,x2);cout<<char(15);
   gotoxy(i,y2);cout<<char(15);
  }
 for(int j=x;j<=y2;j++)
  {
   gotoxy(x,j);cout<<char(15);
   gotoxy(y,j);cout<<char(15);
  }
}
void title()
{
 cout<<"                                                                    \n";
 cout<<"                                                                    \n";
 cout<<"                                                                    \n";
 cout<<"                                                                    \n";
 cout<<"                                                                    \n";
 cout<<"       Ûßßßß      ÜßßßÜ      ÜßßßÜ       ÛßÛ       ÛßßßÜ     Ûßßßß  \n";
 cout<<"       ÛÜÜÜ       ßÜÜÜ       Û      Û   Û      Û   Û     ÛÜÜÜ   \n";
 cout<<"       Û              Û      Û         ÛßßßßßÛ     Ûßßß      Û      \n";
 cout<<"       ÛÜÜÜÜ      ßÜÜÜß      ßÜÜÜß     Û     Û     Û         ÛÜÜÜÜ  \n";
 cout<<"       ±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±±  \n";
 cout<<"                                                                    \n";
 delay(2000);
 cout<<"                                                                    \n";
 cout<<"                                                                    \n";
 cout<<"                               ÞFROM THE RIDDLERÞ                   \n";
 cout<<"                                                                    \n";
 cout<<"                                                                    \n";
 delay(2500);
}

void introsound()
{
 sound(20);
 }

void cont()
{
 gotoxy(25,21);cprintf("Press any key to continue...");
}

void name()
{
 textcolor(15);gotoxy(3,3),cprintf("Enter your name: ");
 cin>>namee;
 }


void prologue()
{
 textcolor(15);gotoxy(5,10),cprintf("You live in the Philippines in the place of Taguig \n");
 delay(2000);
 textcolor(15);gotoxy(5,11),cprintf("You have parents and a brother that loves and supports you\n");
 delay(2000);
 textcolor(15);gotoxy(5,12),cprintf("Friends that are there when you needed \n");
 delay(2000);
 textcolor(15);gotoxy(5,13),cprintf("Your life is great and almost perfect\n");
 delay(2000);
 textcolor(15);gotoxy(5,14),cprintf("All of a sudden, you woke up in a house and doesn't remember a thing...");
 delay(2000);
 cont();
 getch();
}


void main()
{
 char c;
 _setcursortype(_NOCURSOR);
 textcolor(4);
 clrscr();
 introsound();
 title();
 cont();
 delay(getch());
 textcolor(4);
 box1(1,79,1,24);
 prologue();
 nosound();
 clrscr();
 textcolor(4);
 box1(1,79,1,24);
 textcolor(15);gotoxy(2,2),cprintf("You: W--W--who--am I? What am I doing here? A-aaa-argh, my head hurts.\n");
  sound(9000);
  delay(2500);
  gotoxy(2,3),cprintf("Can't remember anything!");
  delay(2000);
  gotoxy(2,4),cprintf("--You found a letter beside your bed--");
  delay(2000);
  gotoxy(2,5),cprintf("--You picked it up--"),item();
  delay(1500);
  box2();
  letter();
  delay(1500);
  gotoxy(2,6),cprintf("--You opened it--");
  delay(1500);
  clrscr();
  textcolor(4);
  box1(1,79,1,24);
  letter1();
  nosound();
 }
```

I want to pause or maybe exit the game while the main() codes are running. Is there any way?

Comment: Do some reading about *states* and *flags*. And of course about *loops* and *events*.